# Schrodinger Operator with Finite Discrete Spectrum in $(-\infty, -1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

I'm reading parts of Reed and Simon's [Analysis of Operators](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0125850042) and have come across a statement I find puzzling.  They say that if $V$ is a bounded function of compact support on $\mathbb{R}^3$ then $-\Delta + V$ has only finitely many eigenvalues (discrete spectrum) in $(-\infty, -1]$.

**Things I know:**

- The Min-Max Principle
- $\sigma_{ess}(-\Delta) = [0,\infty)$, and for (relatively) compact $V$ then $\sigma_{ess}(-\Delta + V) = \sigma_{ess}(-\Delta)$.
- If $V \in R + (L^\infty)_\epsilon$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ (where $R$ is the Rollnik class) then $\sigma_{ess}(-\Delta + V) = \sigma_{ess}(-\Delta)$.

**My Thoughts:**

It seems that $V \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)$ since it is globally bounded.  At the same time by the Min-Max principle we must have $\mu_n(H)$ is either an eigenvalue below the bottom of the essential spectrum, or is the bottom of the essential spectrum for each $n$ (where $H = -\Delta + V$).  Part of me wants to argue that in this instance we are guaranteed that for some $n, \; \mu_n(H) = \inf \sigma_{ess}(H) = 0$, but this may not be so.  What if from the Min-Max principle we have that there are infinitely many eigenvalues counting multiplicity?  Are we guaranteed to hit the bottom of the essential spectrum at some point using the Min-Max algorithm?

I feel like I'm asking a silly question, tell me if it is!

Comment: If any $\lambda < 0$ were an accumulation point of negative eigenvalues, then $\lambda$ would be in the essential spectrum because $\|f_n\|=1$, $Hf_n=\lambda_n f_n$ and $\lambda_n \uparrow \lambda < 0$ would give $\|(H-\lambda I)f_n\|=|\lambda-\lambda_n|\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: $V$ itself is a relatively compact perturbation, so $\sigma_{ess}(-\Delta+V)=\sigma_{ess}(-\Delta)=[0,\infty)$. (Whether or not a $\mu_n$ equals the bottom of the essential spectrum depends on whether there are infinitely many discrete eigenvalues below $\sigma_{ess}$, but this is not really relevant for the question you asked.)